# using python stdeb to update already created packages

Tags: python, deb

I am using stdeb to create python debian package. I have already created the package and it's in our distribution repo. Now I made some source code changes and want to update the package with new changes. When i used `python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb` to update the package, it gives an error `ValueError: more than one directory in deb_dist. Unsure which is source directory`. I would presume this is because deb_dist folder already exists. Can someone guide me on how to update the package without deleting deb_dist folder? I want to keep the history of changes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% that this is the correct "debian" way of doing this but these are the steps I took, If anyone else knows a more correct way, I would be interested.
(Based on instructions at https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Packaging
)
In your main source directory (where setup.py lives)

Bump version number in setup.py and generate a new source tarball

```
python setup.py sdist
```

Copy the generated tarball to your debian build directory (default is deb_dist) and rename to meet debian standards i.e. `<package>_<version>.orig.tar.gz`

```
cp dist/<package>-<version>.tar.gz deb_dist/<package>_<version>.orig.tar.gz
```

In the directory where your debian directory is (default is deb_dist/

```
uupdate <path to updated source>_orig.tar.gz
```

This should generate a new package directory keeping your old debian files and add a new entry to the changelog.